# pathForResource is returning null?

Tags: ios, filepath

I copied a mp4 format file into my XCode. named as abc.mp4

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" ofType:@"mp4"];
```

As I log filePath, it return me null.

How can I access my XCode resources files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have not checked the box to include that file. What you show is an attempt to fetch the file "abc.mp4" from your bundle.

Look in the target's build phases, and make sure that file is being copied to the bundle.

Comment: Sir it is in Project Directory, copied. I like to fetch it so that I can convert it into NSData and send to server.